# Is the hostname changeable?

Tags: nanoframework

the default hostname of nanoFramework is nanodevice_xxxxxx (xxxxxx = Mac-Address), is it posible to set an individual name?
Like Networkconfig.Hostname = "xxx" and a save function and after reboot is the new hostname activ.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not supported. We are considering adding this feature.